# Android Device Movement Speed

Tags: android, google-maps

I need to calculate the movement speed on every location update.

I'm using the following code for the location update.

```
public class FlirtLocationListener implements LocationListener
{
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) 
    {

                // My Code on the location update
    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) 
    {
        Log.i("OnProviderDisabled", "OnProviderDisabled");
    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) 
    {

        Log.i("onProviderEnabled", "onProviderEnabled");
    }
    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
            Bundle extras) 
    {
        Log.i("onStatusChanged", "onStatusChanged");
    }
}
```

How to get the movement speed? Should I calculate the time between the two updates and the distance between first and next location? Or is there some other way?

Comment: Umm, have you looked at the Location class?  There is a getSpeed() method.

Comment: Wow, thanks sir @jsmith :) Answer it like an answer not comment, so I can accept and upvote your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @jsmith said there is a `getSpeed()` method in the `Location.class`.

```
public class LocationListener implements LocationListener
    {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) 
        {
               float speed = location.getSpeed();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

But, location.getSpeed() gives null value. You must specify the setSpeed() to get location which may not be accurate. So, can calculate the speed using simple mathematical formula.
Speed = distance/time.

Comment: Since this was for Google Maps Api v1, lots of things are changed since then.